# I'm having trouble swapping the strings in an array in Linux x86_64 assembly language

Tags: string, sorting, assembly, yasm

I want to implement bubblesort and quicksort in x86_64 assembly language on Linux, but I'm having a lot of trouble. I can't get a basic swap routine (swapij) to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

The program is built with:

```
yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 -o testStr.obj testStr.asm
gcc -g -z noexecstack testStr.obj -o testStr
```

Comment: Swapping the actual strings during sorting is impractical, especially since they don't have the same length. It's much easier to sort pointers to the strings. Afterwards you can rearrange the strings based on the sorted pointer array, if you like.

Comment: Write up your algorithm in C, using pointers as  you are, and make sure it works by running & testing it.  It's really not that much work and you'll have learned a lot regarding the development of your sorting algorithm implementation.  Then take that C code to assembly piece by piece and rather literally, and it will run the same as the C code.  We need to understand conceptually what we're trying to do and that makes writing assembly so much easier.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you want `default rel` to make addressing modes like `[pTempj]` use more efficient RIP-relative addressing.  `default abs` is unfortunately the default in NASM and YASM.

Comment: Why did you include the code snippet twice? At first glance, it would appear both these snippets are identical.

Comment: To edit your question, you click [edit].  (Either the link in my comment, or the word edit above, right below the tags.)  Same as you did on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

### You don't have the necessary buffers

> ```
> section     .data
> pTempi      db  64
> pTempj      db  64
> ```

These `db`s just side aside a single byte each (preloaded with the value 64). What you need is something like:

```
section     .bss
pTempi      resb  64
pTempj      resb  64
```

### Doesn't your `strcpy` need to be told how many bytes to copy?

> ```
> mov     rcx, r8
> lea     rdi, [pTempi]
> call    getElement          ; rdi contains str from array[i]
> strcpy
> ```

You provide destination and source addresses, but I don't see you pass an actual length to `strcpy`.
Also, pay extra attention to the comments that you write. Upon returning from *getElement*, it is RSI that points to the string in the i-th 64-byte record of the array. And a mention like "contains str" is definitely confusing/wrong since the register does not contain any characters from the string. Instead the register contains a pointer to a certain string.

Comment: `strcpy(char *rdi, const char *rsi)` copies implicit-length C strings.  It figures out the length from the string data.  You're thinking of `memcpy(dst=rdi, src=rsi, len=rdx)`.  I don't see a custom definition of `strcpy` so the OP seems to be using glibc, but with a nonsense calling convention.  RCX is the first arg for Windows x64, the 4th arg for x86-64 SysV.  And R8 and R9 are both call-clobbered, but the OP's code reads R9 after the first `strcpy`.

Comment: Or wait, it's not `call strcpy`, they just wrote `strcpy`.  So it has to be a macro they're not showing.  Given the name, it *shouldn't* take a length parameter, otherwise it should be named `memcpy`, but we don't know.  That could explain the custom calling convention with pointers left somewhere when `getElement` returns.

Comment: @PeterCordes There are many unknowns in the question, so who knows? eg. Why do they show us those 11 strings? Those strings surely have to be copied first to an array of fixed-sized records. Only the lack of the temporary buffers really remains.

Comment: Yeah, it's insufficient to answer with a fix, although we can say that swapping two strings of different lengths is impossible when they're packed head-to-tail like this, unless we also move the intervening string data by the difference in gap size.  But `strcpy` is a standard well-known name, so the default assumption should be that it matches the behaviour of the standard C function.  (And thus we should be questioning lack of comments about the custom calling convention, but not the lack of passing a length.  The string data is declared with `EOL` marks, not lengths, too.)